# Why is this git merge not working?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm having a problem with Git I can't figure out. I have a simple HTML file in my master branch. On that file, there is a word, 'mispl1'. I have a branch off of master named "fixMispl1". I check it out, change "mispl1" to "misspell1", and commit the change.

So now if I switch to master, in Eclipse I can see "mispell1" changed to "mispl1", and if I switch back to "fixMispl1", I see it change back to "mispl1".

So the problem is, I'm trying to merge fixMispl1 into master. I switch to master, then type `git merge fixMispl1`, and nothing happens. I get a message saying "Already up-to-date." But I know it's not up to date, because the word changes every time I switch branches.

Comment: Could you post the first few lines of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`?

Comment: Try rebase your branch off master then merge it after (it shouldnt make a difference in this case, but who knows...)

Comment: @FelipeSkinner:  Be careful next time you edit this question.  Adding the code formatting around the branches didn't really help anything, and you managed to actually change the intent of one of the commands (which would have been an entirely different problem as described).

Comment: Try pushing the `fixMispl1 ` branch before the merge.  Maybe it is trying to merge with the remote version of that branch.  I would try it manually using the commandline and avoid the eclipse just to bypass any weird things it might be doing.

Comment: Did you check why this change is not happening change "mispl1" to "misspell1" on **fixMispl1**?

Comment: @Makoto ops sorry. but about the command, he actually misspelled it. He said the branch had the variable as "misspell1" and when he switch back there it goes to "mispl1"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I figured it out. As a test, I had already merged the two branches into master and pushed to GitHub. I wanted to redo the test, so I changed master back to its beginning state, committed, checked out the first branch, made changes, and things started getting confusing from there (i.e. the 'Already up-to-date' messages).

So instead I deleted both branches, created 2 new branches of the same name, made the same changes in them, committed, merged into master (resolving conflicts along the way, which was the point of the test), and it all worked as expected. I could just as easily have created new branches from master without deleting the old ones, but I wanted to keep the same branch names.